# Oracle replace all characters before "." dot

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace all characters with nothing before the `.` character and also replace all `[` and `]` with nothing.
Please see examples below:

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| `[PINWHEEL_ASSET].[MX5530]` | `MX5530` |
| `[PINWHEEL_TRADE].[AR5403]` | `AR5403` |

The parts before and after the `.` dot are variables.

Comment: Can either the dot or the square brackets appear anywhere else, other than exactly once as a separator, and respectively exactly twice as the delimiters for the "first" and "second" part of the string?

Comment: Nope they cannot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
  sample_data (my_string) as (
    select '[PINWHEEL_ASSET].[MX5530]' from dual
  )
select rtrim(substr(my_string, instr(my_string, '.') + 2), ']') as second_part
from   sample_data
;




SECOND_PART
-----------
MX5530
```

This assumes that the input string looks exactly like this: `[first].[second]`, where "first" and "second" are (possibly empty) strings that do not contain periods or closing brackets.

Comment: HI what if I have teh srting [Entity].[EN_SNL].[EN_Sea_Supplier]  and need to return only the EN_Sea_Supplier?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use regular expressions (see line #6).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '[PINWHEEL_ASSET].[MX5530]' from dual union all
  3     select '[PINWHEEL_TRADE].[AR5403]' from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select col,
  6         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, 2) result
  7  from test;

COL                       RESULT
------------------------- --------------------
[PINWHEEL_ASSET].[MX5530] MX5530
[PINWHEEL_TRADE].[AR5403] AR5403

SQL>
```